# android jetpack compose is Hilt decreases app startup time?

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, app-startup

I am trying to improve my app startup time, which is currently is on roughly 4s+-
I am using MVVM clean architecture and compose only app, no fragments.

I tend to think that what cause my app to launch slowly is the view models that I create using Hilt during the onCreate. this is my onCreate method in the MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)        
    setContent {
        val themeViewModel: ThemeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val uiState by themeViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

        val darkTheme = when (uiState.displayTheme) {
            ThemeOption.AUTO -> isSystemInDarkTheme()
            ThemeOption.LIGHT -> false
            ThemeOption.DARK -> true
        }

        MainAppTheme(darkTheme = darkTheme) {
            MainApp(admobCustomService = admobCustomService)
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I initiate the MainApp with all the view models:

```
@Composable
fun MainApp(
    connectableViewModel: ConnectableViewModel= hiltViewModel(),
    controlViewModel: ControlViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    screenA_ViewModel: ScreenA_ViewModel= hiltViewModel(),
    bluetoothViewModel: BluetoothViewModel= hiltViewModel(),
    screenB_ViewModel: ScreenB_ViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    screenC_ViewModel: ScreenC_ViewModel= hiltViewModel(),
    screenD_ViewModel: ScreenD_ViewModel= hiltViewModel(),
    screenE_ViewModel: ScreenE_ViewModel= hiltViewModel(),
    screenF_ViewModel: ScreenF_ViewModel= hiltViewModel(),
    screenG_ViewModel: ScreenG_ViewModel= hiltViewModel(),
    admobCustomService: AdmobCustomService,
) {
    val appState = rememberRemoteControlAppState(
        admobCustomService = admobCustomService,
        activity = LocalContext.current.findActivity()
    )

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),

   ...

}
```

am I using Hilt correctly? should I inject the view models differently? what if I want to use the same instance of a viewmodel in multiple screens? (this is the main reason I created them as soon as possible).

any other thoughts on how to check what cause the startup time so long?

thanks